# i recieved many crash after i received pasteboard content changed notification

Tags: ios, uipasteboard

i recieved many crash after i received pasteboard content changed notification. i just monitor the change of pasteboard, and try to recognize the text content.

here is my code:

```
        class PasteboardMonitor {

            init() {
                addPasteboardMonitor()
            }

            func addPasteboardMonitor() {

                handleContentFromPasteBoard(conent: UIPasteboard.general.string, identifier: "\(UIPasteboard.general.changeCount)")

                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didReceivedPasteboardNotification(noti:)), name: UIPasteboard.changedNotification, object: nil)
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didReceivedPasteboardNotification(noti:)), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didReceivedApplicationNotification), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
            }

           func handleContentFromPasteBoard(conent: String?, identifier: String? = nil) {
                //handle content
                ...
           }

           @objc func didReceivedPasteboardNotification(noti: Notification) {
                handleContentFromPasteBoard(conent: UIPasteboard.general.string, identifier: "\(UIPasteboard.general.changeCount)")
            }
```

the crash log is:

- Crashed: com.apple.UIKit.pasteboard.cache-queue
- 0   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1963b5a38 ___chkstk_darwin + 64
- 1   libdispatch.dylib              0x19635f49c _dispatch_mach_send_and_wait_for_reply + 440
- 2   libdispatch.dylib              0x19635f904 dispatch_mach_send_with_result_and_wait_for_reply + 56
- 3   libxpc.dylib                   0x19629f594 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 240
- 4   Foundation                     0x196ba51fc **NSXPCCONNECTION_IS_WAITING_FOR_A_SYNCHRONOUS_REPLY** + 16
- 5   Foundation                     0x19696b090 -[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:] + 2704
- 6   Foundation                     0x19696a40c -[NSXPCConnection _sendSelector:withProxy:arg1:] + 128
- 7   Foundation                     0x196bac2ac _NSXPCDistantObjectSimpleMessageSend1 + 40
- 8   Pasteboard                     0x1ac476aac -[PBServerConnection localGeneralPasteboard:]
- 9   UIKitCore                      0x19a6c3428 _getTemporaryLocalGeneralPasteboard + 64
- 10  UIKitCore                      0x19a6c2444 _pasteboardCacheQueue_existingItemCollectionWithName + 152
- 11  UIKitCore                      0x19a6c2160 __59+[_UIConcretePasteboard _pasteboardNamed:createIfNotFound:]_block_invoke + 236
- 12  libdispatch.dylib              0x196349fd8 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
- 13  libdispatch.dylib              0x1963567f4 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 60
  ...
- 218 UIKitCore                      0x19a6c1fcc +[_UIConcretePasteboard _pasteboardNamed:createIfNotFound:] + 396
- 219 TovApp                       0x1014e4a54 PasteboardMonitor.didReceivedPasteboardNotification(noti:) + 123 (PasteboardMonitor.swift:123)
- 220 TovApp                       0x1014e4c4c @objc PasteboardMonitor.didReceivedPasteboardNotification(noti:) + 4351249484 (:4351249484)
- 221 Foundation                     0x196a6effc __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_2 + 28
- 222 CoreFoundation                 0x1965fc99c **CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER** + 28
- 223 CoreFoundation                 0x1965fc9ec ___CFXRegistrationPost1_block_invoke + 68
- 224 CoreFoundation                 0x1965fbce4 _CFXRegistrationPost1 + 396
- 225 CoreFoundation                 0x1965fb97c ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 108
- 226 CoreFoundation                 0x196574910 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1424
- 227 CoreFoundation                 0x1965fb2ac _CFXNotificationPost + 1268
- 228 Foundation                     0x19695db8c -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64
- 229 UIKitCore                      0x19a6c1cd4 _sendPasteboardChangedNotification + 96
- 230 UIKitCore                      0x19a6c1fcc +[_UIConcretePasteboard _pasteboardNamed:createIfNotFound:] + 396
- 231 TovApp                       0x1014e4a54 PasteboardMonitor.didReceivedPasteboardNotification(noti:) + 123 (PasteboardMonitor.swift:123)
- 232 TovApp                       0x1014e4c4c @objc PasteboardMonitor.didReceivedPasteboardNotification(noti:) + 4351249484 (:4351249484)
- 233 Foundation                     0x196a6effc __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_2 + 28
- 234 CoreFoundation                 0x1965fc99c **CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER** + 28
- 235 CoreFoundation                 0x1965fc9ec ___CFXRegistrationPost1_block_invoke + 68
- 236 CoreFoundation                 0x1965fbce4 _CFXRegistrationPost1 + 396
- 237 CoreFoundation                 0x1965fb97c ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 108
- 238 CoreFoundation                 0x196574910 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1424
- 239 CoreFoundation                 0x1965fb2ac _CFXNotificationPost + 1268
- 240 Foundation                     0x19695db8c -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64
- 241 UIKitCore                      0x19a6c1cd4 _sendPasteboardChangedNotification + 96
- 242 UIKitCore                      0x19a6c1fcc +[_UIConcretePasteboard _pasteboardNamed:createIfNotFound:] + 396
- 243 TovApp                       0x1014e4a54 PasteboardMonitor.didReceivedPasteboardNotification(noti:) + 123 (PasteboardMonitor.swift:123)
- 244 TovApp                       0x1014e4c4c @objc PasteboardMonitor.didReceivedPasteboardNotification(noti:) + 4351249484 (:4351249484)
- 245 Foundation                     0x196a6effc __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_2 + 28
- 246 CoreFoundation                 0x1965fc99c **CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER** + 28
- 247 CoreFoundation                 0x1965fc9ec ___CFXRegistrationPost1_block_invoke + 68
- 248 CoreFoundation                 0x1965fbce4 _CFXRegistrationPost1 + 396
- 249 CoreFoundation                 0x1965fb97c ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 108
- 250 CoreFoundation                 0x196574910 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1424
- 251 CoreFoundation                 0x1965fb2ac _CFXNotificationPost + 1268
- 252 Foundation                     0x19695db8c -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64
- 253 UIKitCore                      0x19a6c1cd4 _sendPasteboardChangedNotification + 96
- 254 UIKitCore                      0x19a6c1fcc +[_UIConcretePasteboard _pasteboardNamed:createIfNotFound:] + 396
- 255 TovApp                       0x1014e4a54 PasteboardMonitor.didReceivedPasteboardNotification(noti:) + 123 (PasteboardMonitor.swift:123)

do anybody know why this occurs? and how to fix it? thanks.

Comment: no, the crash logs collect by firebase from product enviroment

Answer (score 0):

Your code related to `NotificationCenter` looks risky.

Try:

1. Ensuring you add observer only once:

```
var observersAdded: Bool = false

func addPasteboardMonitor() {
    ...
    if !observersAdded {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self ....
        observersAdded = true
    }
    ...
}
```

2. Removing observers in the destructor of `PasteboardMonitor`: `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver`

Comment: PasteboardMonitor is a singleton, and init in main thread. so i can sure add observer only once.